# Using URL of JSON file on local drive with OpenLayers support?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-2, json

When i save json file in web apps then using `http://localhost:8080/WGSClient/js/object.json` this path file gets open.

But when i keep it outside web apps like local folder then using same url format json file is not accessible.

It showing error that OpenLayers doesn't support this url format.

So what is the proper url which OpenLayers support or i should keep my json file in web apps?

What would be the URL of a JSON file on the local drive?

Comment: Do you mean file:// style URLS?

Comment: http://localhost/localpath  type URL

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [file URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)? You can try the following format

```
file://host/path
```

For example, if you want the file fstab at /etc/

```
file://localhost/etc/fstab
```

You can also omit the host but don't omit the slash

```
file:///etc/fstab
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: file://localhost/etc/fstab
using this URI error occurs.Access to restricted URI denied.but when i keep it in web apps then using http://localhost/path it runs successfully

Comment: Using file://localhost/etc/fstab URI code shows error that 'access to restricted URI denied'..I think openlayers doesn't supports this type of URI.May be it supports http://localhost type of URL

Comment: Can you try it for other files? fstab is a system file. What about files in your home folder?

Comment: file://localhost/my file path. not successfully running.same error as access denied for restricted url

Comment: Browser support for these type of URLs is patchy for security reasons.  Chrome especially will reject localhost and file://.  Use an actual web server with real domains.  It is not difficult to setup and will be better.

Comment: @user9125 What about the `file:///etc/fstab` format? Though I second what Matthew said.

Comment: I think im using it in openlayers and it only supports http://localhost format.as i said when i keep file in web apps then using http://localhost/path format file gets opened.But not running when i keep it outside web apps like in local folder.